# is it possible to make css overlays ontop of an image with specific area?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to make a big map for my fantasy map project, the map itself is a lossless .WebP image. Is it possible if I can make CSS overlay with specific coordinates based on `<area target="" href="" coords="" shape="poly">`. And with that information I'd make it so that it would generate SVG for the actual overlay, then making it dark with opacity when I hover over that specific area only.

Since I have no idea how to do this I tried watching several [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-9YQUmTOdI&t=26s), but they're always referencing the actual base image in .svg, then they used coordinates from the actual .svg base image itself to make it work. But the issue is that my image is in .WebP format image, which in this case is pretty different, and I can't just convert it to .svg without countless hours of work.
Currently, the codes are :

HTML

```
<div class="map">
      <img src="https://github.com/DylonKejhu/DylonKejhu.github.io/blob/main/resources/images/AurelisMap.webp" usemap="#image-map">
      <map name="image-map">
      <area target="" alt="DylonKejhu Union" title="DylonKejhu Union" href="/countries/dku.html" coords="3787,1099,3804,1126,3795,1183,3809,1223,3778,1263,3787,1298,3817,1303,3870,1347,3915,1351,3946,1338,3981,1316,4016,1320,4047,1307,4140,1276,4224,1294,4290,1303,4325,1303,4361,1289,4409,1272,4462,1267,4511,1232,4507,1188,4502,1161,4489,1099,4454,1068,4449,1033,4484,1007,4520,1007,4560,1015,4590,1020,4630,1011,4666,967,4696,958,4714,914,4776,861,4670,790,4643,773,4502,711,4462,715,4383,813,4325,816,4277,790,4228,790,4188,781,4162,746,4113,728,4074,728,4038,759,3954,834,3902,891,3857,900,3813,931,3774,953,3818,1010,3787,1046" shape="poly">
      </map>
</div>
```

css

```
.map {
     height: 750px;
     width: 100%;
     overflow: scroll;
     Border: 12px double black;
}
```